# Why C++ template code runs faster in my lambdas?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, lambda

I've been doing some simple vector data accumulate tests and wondering why the following code:

```
template<typename T>
T accum(typename vector<T>::const_iterator first, typename vector<T>::const_iterator last, T init) {
  for(; first != last; ++first)
    init += *first;
  return init;
}
```

runs faster than the following code (both in lamda) ?

```
test("Iterator/direct", table, [](auto& values) {
  auto sum {0.0};
  for(auto i = values.begin(); i != values.end(); ++i)
    sum += *i;
  return(sum);
});
```

In my eyes the algorithm itself should be quite much the same.

The whole source code (53 lines) can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/porssimies/5acb09d685b3c56f650981d7e5d529ec).

Comment: This question is almost meaningless, it depends on the optimizations used by the compiler. The only thing is that `sum` in the second version is always `double`.

Comment: When you ask about performance then provide information about compiler and command line options.

Comment: There are two difference between these versions: 1. lambda uses non-const iterators, 2. lambda calls end() on every iteration. If you compile without optimization (-O0) this really makes a difference however with optimization (-O2) the performance difference is practically negligible.

Comment: Enter the code in Compiler Explorer and study the output assembly. You will likely get different results in different compilers and optimization levels. https://godbolt.org/

Comment: r3mus n0x You're correct. When optimized a difference will be the "same". Thank you.

Comment: schteppe Great advice! Will do this.

Comment: Your test measures wall clock time rather than CPU time. This only works if yours is the only process producing significant load on the machine. Otherwise it can be totally meaningless. `std::chrono` doesn't provide a way to measure CPU time, but C `clock` function does (unless you are on Windows).

Comment: n. 'pronouns' m. Thx for the info. I'll try that.

Comment: After reading this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock I changed the high_resolution_clock to steady_clock which should be real ticks not the wall clock. But I have to say it doesn't make a big difference on desktop computers running operating systems like windows :)

Comment: Any kind of profiling or performance comparison has to be done with optimizations enabled to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with -O2 option and the execution times will be practically negligible. Thank you very much for all commenters.